# How to call webservice using javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services, html-components

I am using below code to call webservice using javascript:

```
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
       <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
      service = document.getElementById("ViewLink");

     function InitializeService(){
      service.useService('http://myURL/cloudtalk/cloudservice.asmx?wsdl',"CloudService");
     }
     var regtype, regvalue;
     function registerUser(){
      regtype = document.getElementById("Text1").value;
      regvalue =document.getElementById("Text2").value;

      service.CloudService.callService("register", regtype, regvalue);
     }
     function ShowResult(){
    alert(event.result.value);
      }
     </script>
</head>
<body  onload="InitializeService()" id="service" >
<a id="ViewLink"   href="http://"  onclick="registerUser()"  style="behavior:url(webservice.htc);" onresult="onmyresult();"> <font color=maroon>Call</font></a>
  <input id="Text1" type="text" />
        <input id="Text2" type="text" />
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Save" onclick="registerUser();" />     
</body>
```

But i am getting error:"The url is not valid and cannot be loaded"

i done the above code with help of below urls but i checked both samples in these url are not working:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/callWebServiceUsingJS.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/CallWebServiceFromHtml.aspx

NOTE: my web service is live and i am able to consume it using asp.net but i am facing issue for using it in javascript.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Does `http://myURL/cloudtalk/cloudservice.asmx?wsdl` in your browser?

Comment: What about **not** using IE-only stuff?

Comment: @i wants to consume my service in all browsers using javascript

Comment: @deiga:my web service is live and i am able to consume it using asp.net but i am facing issue for using it in javascript.

Comment: I think its not working because of cross domain, experts is it correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the web service URL has a different host (by domain name or port) than the one from which the HTML page is served then your JavaScript is violating the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and any browser will prevent the web service request from loading.